# SQL Join - If it doesn't find any, try another parameters

Tags: sql

Let's suppose we have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON b.number = a.number 
                  AND b.name = a.name 
                  AND b.place = a.place
```

If that `LEFT JOIN` doesn't find nothing, I need to change the `ON` parameters to something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON b.number = a.number 
                  AND b.person = a.person
```

That second `LEFT JOIN` only needs to run if the first one doesn't return nothing. How can I achieve that behaviour?

---

I have already tried with an `OR` statement, but doesn't work because the first `LEFT JOIN` always need to be checked first, and not at the same time that the second.

Comment: A left join means always all of the records in TableA will get returned. Query 1 and Query 2 will return all of the rows. Perhaps you meant a "join" on tableA and tableB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest method is `union all`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM tableA a JOIN
     tableB b
     ON b.number = a.number AND
        b.name = a.name AND
        b.place = a.place
UNION ALL
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM tableA a JOIN
     tableB b
     ON b.number = a.number AND
        b.person = a.person 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tableB b
                  WHERE b.number = a.number AND
                        b.name = a.name AND
                        b.place = a.place
                 );
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! If I need to use a `WHERE` clause, it needs to be places in both `SELECT`s?

Comment: @ThRnk . . . Yes.